# I’m getting a primary key constraint when I try to create data in grails

Tags: grails, hql

I’m getting a primary key constraint when I try to create data …

```
class BootStrap {      
def init = { servletContext ->
     new ListItPlan(m_id: "248656", plan_id: "12345XX9876543").save()
     new ListItPlan(m_id: "209459", plan_id: "12345XX9876543").save()
     new ListItPlan(m_id: "248656", plan_id: "56748XXX123933").save()
     new ListItPlan(m_id: "209459", plan_id: "56748XXX123933").save() 

     new Plan(plan_id: "12345XX9876543", p_id_type: "PLAN-ID").save()         
     new Plan(plan_id: "56748XXX123933", p_id_type: "PLAN-ID").save() 

     new Cred(m_id: "248656", d_name: "Lorem Ipsum").save()
     new Cred(m_id: "209459", d_name: "Ipsum").save()     
}     
def destroy = {     } }
```

I did some more research and revised it a bit.  I’ve tried different things , but I guess I’m just not understanding how to construct the data.  I’ve tried things like this…

```
def d1 = new Cred(m_id: "248656", d_name: "Lorem Ipsum").save(failOnError:     true) 
def ldp1 = new ListItPlan(Cred : d1, plan_id: "12345XX9876543").save(failOnError: true)
```

…but I can’t get it to populate the tables. Please help….

My model…

```
class ListItPlan {
    String m_id
    String plan_id      
    static hasMany = [creds : Cred, plans : Plan]

    static constraints = {
        m_id()
        plan_id()
    }
}
```

---

```
class Cred {
    String m_id
    String g_name
    static belongsTo = [owner : ListItPlan]
    static hasMany = [plans : Plan]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

---

```
class Plan {
    String plan_id
    String plan_id_type
    static belongsTo = [listItPlan : ListItPlan, cred: Cred]

    static constraints = {  
    }
}
```

How do I write the proper statement to get data into the tables...based on the structure of my model?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The title includes "I’m getting a primary key constraint". You are supposed to get a primary key constraint.  If you are saying that you get an error related to the constraint, can you show the details of that error?

Comment: You have several `belongsTo` relationships that are not being initialized but they need to be in order to create valid presentable instances.  I haven't run your code but I would expect that the errors are not because of a primary key constraint.  The saves should not even be sent to the database because validation is almost certainly failing when you try to save those `Plan` instances.

Answer (score -1):

if m_id is a "primary key" on the table you are inserting on, it must be unique. You have the same key twice on yours.

Try this:

```
new ListItPlan(m_id: "1", plan_id: "12345XX9876543").save()
new ListItPlan(m_id: "2", plan_id: "12345XX9876543").save()
new ListItPlan(m_id: "3", plan_id: "56748XXX123933").save()
new ListItPlan(m_id: "4", plan_id: "56748XXX123933").save()
```

Comment: The source code for `ListItPlan` is in the original question and the way that it is written, the default `id` property would be the primary key.